# How to use flavour in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

how to use Flavour in flutter app that can be work in Android and iOS

For Native Android we are use

```
 productFlavors {
       flavour1{
             applicationId 'your package'
             versionCode 1
             versionName "1.0"
               }
           flavour2{
             applicationId 'your package'
             versionCode 1
             versionName "1.0"
               }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for android :

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

flavorDimensions "app"
productFlavors {

    app1 {
        dimension "app"
        applicationId "com.example.test1"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    app2 {
        dimension "app"
        applicationId "com.example.test2"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```